# How many solutions in n x n matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, whose column vectors are linearly independent; How many solutions does the homogeneous linear system $A\mathbf{x}=0$ have?

Could any one help to how to solve the above one?

Comment: What do you think? What do you know about square matrices with linearly independent columns?

Comment: @ Casteels If the rows of A are linearly independent, then the result of doing row-reduction to A is the identity matrix maybe?

Comment: Yes that's correct - and the rows of $A$ are linearly independent if and only if the columns of $A$ are (but that is not quite an obvious observation at first - have you learned that theorem yet?) Have you learned about the inverse of a matrix?

Comment: @Casteels I just checked out online about the inverse of a matrix. No, I haven't learned it yet. However, the answers that were given make sense to me. I'll need to study the definition of linear independence I suppose. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\dotsc,\vec v_n$ be the linearly independent columns of a matrix $A$. That is,
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec v_1 & \vec v_2 & \dotsb & \vec v_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, suppose $\vec x$ satisfies $A\vec x=\vec 0$. Writing
$$
\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
then implies
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec v_1 & \vec v_2 & \dotsb & \vec v_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}
=
\vec 0\tag{1}
$$
But (1) is equivalent to 
$$
x_1\vec v_1+x_2\vec v_2+\dotsb+x_n\vec v_n=\vec 0\tag{2}
$$
Since $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\dotsc,\vec v_n$ are linearly independent, (2) implies that
$$
x_1=x_2=\dotsb=x_n=0
$$
Hence $\vec x=\vec 0$. That is, the only solution to $A\vec x=\vec 0$ is $\vec x=\vec 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The system $Ax = 0$ has exactly one solution, namely $x = 0$. To reach that conclusion, we only need to know that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

A "mantra" I like to use when teaching linear algebra is that matrix-vector multiplication is *the same thing* as linear combination. That is, the product $Ax$ is the just the linear combination of $A$'s columns, using $x$'s entries as coefficients. If you look at the definition of linear independence, that definition says that such a linear combination could give the zero vector *only* if all the coefficients are zero.